# Which is greater ? Sum of odd power terms or even power terms in the exponential Taylor series?

Tags: functions, summation, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I came across this question, in a book.

> Define $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{{(2n+1)}!} $ and $ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{{(2n)}!} $, where x is a real number. Then, which of the following statements is correct?
>
> (A) $f(x) > g(x)$ for all x
>
> (B) $f(x) < g(x)$ for all x
>
> (C) $f(x) = g(x)$ for all x
>
> (D) none of the above statements need necessarily hold for all x

I tried to write out the Taylor series for $e^{-x}$ and used the fact that the series would still be positive and hence concluded that the sum of even powered terms must be greater than the odd powered terms, id est, statement (B).

However, the answer key given in the book says it should be option (A). Is there any thing wrong with my approach?

Comment: $f(0) = 0 < 1 = g(0)$. Your approach seems reasonable.

Comment: In fact, $f$ is the series for $\sinh$ and $g$ the series for $\cosh$, which satisfy $1 + \sinh^2 x = \cosh^2 x$; this together with the observation that $g$ is positive give that (B) is correct.

Comment: Looks like $g(x)-f(x)=e^{-x} > 0$.  So $g(x) > f(x)$, and the answer is B.

Comment: Duh! I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $2f(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$ and $2g(x)=e^x+e^{-x}$, so $g(x)\gt f(x)$.

Comment: What!? For f to be greater than g, $e^{-x} $ has to be negative, which it can't.

Answer (score 2):

A can not possibly be correct
because, for negative x,
f(x) < 0
and
g(x) > 0.

My choice is D,
but I don't have a proof right now.

Comment: That is what I too thought. f(x) comes out to be sinh(x) and g(x) = cosh(x) and  sinh(x) is negative for negative x always.

Comment: So I was wrong (about which is correct). Not the first time, won't be the last.